# Polymorphism or inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a theoretical question about C++. It was part of the final exam at my university and I want to know why the method `f` of class `B` is called, while it should be derived by the base class `A`. Since it is not virtual shouldn't the A::f() be called?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class A{
     public:int f(int x){
               cout<< x << " ";
     }
};
class B:public A{
     public:int f(int y){
                A::f(y+1);
     }
};
void g(A a, B b) {
       a.f(3);
       b.f(3);
 }

int main()
{
  B p; 
  B q; 
  g(p,q);
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

// result is 3 4
```

Comment: This code is horrible. Is the slicing here intended? Why the pass by value?

Answer (score 2):

The static type if `b` in `g()` is `B`, thus there is no need for virtual here - the compiler can know [at compile time] you want to invoke `B::f()`, and that is exactly what he is doing. 
In here, the class `B` redefined `A`'s `f()`, and hides it, so invoking `f()` from a variable whose static type is `B` results in invoking `B::f()`

Note that the `virtual` keyword allows you to use overriding methods where the static type is the parent's type.

Answer (score 2):

The method `g` takes two arguments, of type `A` and `B` repsectively. Since these are no pointer or reference types, dynamic binding does not apply. The compiler knows at compile time the actual type of the objects, and does a static method call.

`virtual` methods only apply if you have pointers or references!

Answer (score 1):

The function `int f(int)` in class `B` "hides" the function with the same name and signature in its base class.

So, when you call `b.f(3);`, and the variable `b` has type `B`, you are calling `B::f`.

Virtual functions are only needed if you want `b.f(3)` to call `B::f` in cases where the type of the *variable* `b` is `A&`, but the *object* it refers to has runtime type `B`. In that situation, the function called would be `B::f` if `A::f` is virtual, but `A::f` is called if non-virtual.

Virtual function calls take the runtime type of objects into account even if they're used via a pointer or reference to a base class. But `B b; b.f(3)` is a call to `B::f` regardless of whether `A::f` even exists, never mind whether it's virtual or non-virtual.

Answer (score 0):

"Non-scientific" explanation:

The function `g` <del>treats `a` as if it was an instance of `A`</del> *gets a copy of `p` as an object of type `A`(see comments below)* , and executes the `f` from within `A`. `b` is treated as an instance of `B`, where the method `B.f` overrides `A.f`, so when `b` is "looked at" as an instance of `B` and we execute `b.f`, the method `B.f` will be executed, because the `A.f` is not visible

If you'd like to call `A.f` using `b.f` you'd have to cast `b` to `A`: `((A)b).f()`.

Comment: "The function g treats a as if it was an instance of A" - because `a` *is* an instance of `A`. It was created by copying the base class subobject of `p`, although since neither class has any data members that's basically a null operation.

Comment: In this specific case `a` is in fact an instance of `B` (initialized in `main` by the line `B p;`) which is treated by `g` as an instance of `A` AFAIK.

Comment: Little terminology: *overrides* is usual reserved for virtual methods. In this instance, `B.f` *hides* `A.f` (I am wary of calling this overload since it has the same parameter).

Comment: No, that's wrong. `a` is not the same object as `p`, because the function `g` takes its parameter by value, and pass-by-value is always a copy. This is C++, not Java. If the signature of `g` was `void g(A &a, B &b)` then you'd be right, `a` would be a reference to `p`.

Comment: @Matthieu: I've seen it called "overload" on the basis that the hidden secret `this` parameter has a different type (or the lhs of the binary `.` operator has a different type if you prefer to look at it that way). But you're absolutely right that "hides" is the term used in the standard, and personally I stopped calling it "overload" when I noticed it causing confusion a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things happening here:

1. You are slicing your object.
2. Your `f()` function is not an override because it is not virtual, and really you should not be doing this.

You would overcome the slicing by making the function g take its first parameter by reference. If A was given a protected copy-constructor that would also prevent it, although then you would not be able to copy genuine instances of A.

In this case your function g will always call `A::f()` even with reference to A because there is no polymorphism. To invoke that you will need to declare `A::f()` as virtual.